# For each in Underscore.JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to loop the items inside URLs

```
<% _.each(jobs, function(job) { %>
    <%= job.get('error') %>
    <%= job.get('urls') %>
<% }); %>
```

Result of above code
false

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]





{
      "error": false,
      "urls": [
        {
          "id": "1",

        },
        {
          "id": "2",

        },
        {
          "id": "3",

        }
      ]
    }
```

How do i loop the Id out

Comment: Define the problem properly. Show us what you tried, the issue, and what you expect.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, expected output. Each element in `urls` array is an object and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. What is your question?

Comment: You can iterate over arrays using `_.each` as well.

Comment: You'd probably use `item.get('id')` or `item.id`.

Comment: @FelixKling Tried that already, is there anyway i can debug?

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: Can you provide expected input, expected output and a code fiddle of what you've tried thus far?

This will help others understand your problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people to benefit 
For debugging do <% console.log('text')%> It helps alot , ignore the comments above, too general , useless.

```
   <% _.each(pins, function(job) { %>
        <% _.each(job.get('urls'), function(item) { %>
            <% console.log(item['id'])%>
        <% }); %>
    <% }); %>
```